# How do I make a Tweet in Zapier code

Tags: javascript, twitter, zapier

The following does not work in the "Code by Zapier" Action.

```
fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=' +encodeURIComponent(textToTweet))
  .then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(function(json) {
    callback(null, json);
  })
  .catch(callback);
```

However, I get the following.

```
errors:
    message:
    Bad Authentication data.
    code:
    215
```

What additional authentication does one need to do? The Twitter account is already connected to Zapier, or does that not matter?

---

UPDATE: per feedback below the following code now gives me an 89: invalid or expired token

```
fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=' +encodeURIComponent(textToTweet), { 
  headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_BEGINSWITH_OWNERID'
  }
})
  .then...............
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward if you know the incantations:

1. Get a token from https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens.
2. Add a `Authorization: Bearer <yourtoken>` header to your `fetch()` call.

And you should be good to go!

Comment: Thank you. I've updated everything but the following code gives me a 89: invalid or expired token

    `fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status='+encodeURIComponent(textToTweet), { 
      headers: {
         Authorization: "Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_STARTING_WITH_OWNERID"
      }
    })
      .then.........`