# How can I authenticate with the Twitter API from Zapier?

Tags: javascript, python, twitter, oauth, zapier

I'm trying to call the Twitter API from Zapier using "Webhooks by Zapier", but do not manage to authenticate correctly via OAuth 1.0.

Using a REST client like Postman, it is a piece of cake. You just pass the consumer key, consumer secret, token and token secret, and set the signature method to HMAC-SHA1. Plus you check "Encode OAuth signature". The client calculates the signature.

I'm looking for a way to calculate this signature in Zapier (possibly using the built-in Python and Javascript modules), but haven't managed so far. If possible, it opens a whole range of possibilities (using the easy connectivity to other apps).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [How do I make a Tweet in Zapier code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624607).

Get that access token and then use your own token and set a header!

Comment: When I use the "access token" as a bearer in the headers, it says "Invalid or expired token".

Comment: I see now what you meant, but it's application only authentication: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only I'm looking to connect via OAuth 1.0, as mentioned above, which also makes it possible to send messages etc: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/single-user